# How can I use functions in switch-case?

Tags: c, function, switch-statement

Hey I searched it but I can't find... I need a function to get information from user in switch case.

```
switch (/* FUNCTION  */) {
```

How can functions can be use in this situation?

Comment: The fact that you are asking the question suggest that you have tried and failed.  In which case, post the code that failed and ask for an explanation.  If you have not yet tried, then do so _before_ asking a question.  If you are simply asking for a function that will receive input, then that is an entirely different question and has little to do with the `switch` construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long at the function returns an integer type, you can do that.  So given:

```
int someFunction( void ) ;
```

Then:

```
switch( someFunction() )
{
    ...
```

is valid.  It is little different than:

```
int x = someFunction() ;
switch( x )
{
    ...
```

but the latter is arguably easier to debug.  For example, you can single-step the latter and know from the value of `x` which case will be entered, and have the opportunity of modifying `x` to force an alternative path.  The former has little merit other than succinctness.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that asks the user for input, then call that function in your switch expression. for example:

```
int getInt(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("enter number:\n");
    if (scanf (" %d", &i)==1) return i;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //...
    switch (getInt()) {
    case 0: printf("Error\n"); break;
    case 1: //...
    case ...
    }
}
```